# How can I extract substrings from a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, string

Consider the following strings:

1) Scheme ID: **abc-456-hu5t10** (**High priority**) *****

2) Scheme ID: **frt-78f-hj542w** (**Balanced**)

3) Scheme ID: **23f-f974-nm54w** (**super formula run**) *****

and so on in the above format - the parts in bold are changes across the strings.

==> *Imagine I've many strings of format Shown above.*
     I want to pick 3 substrings (As shown in BOLD below) from the each of the above strings.

- 1st substring containing the alphanumeric value (in eg above it's "abc-456-hu5t10")
- 2nd substring containing the word (in eg above it's "High priority")
- 3rd substring containing * (`IF` * is present at the end of the string `ELSE` leave it )

How do I pick these 3 substrings from each string shown above? I know it can be done using regular expressions in Perl... Can you help with this?

Comment: Can the string in parentheses itself contain nested parentheses?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
my $data = <<END;
1) Scheme ID: abc-456-hu5t10 (High priority) *
2) Scheme ID: frt-78f-hj542w (Balanced)
3) Scheme ID: 23f-f974-nm54w (super formula run) *
END

foreach (split(/\n/,$data)) {
  $_ =~ /Scheme ID: ([a-z0-9-]+)\s+\(([^)]+)\)\s*(\*)?/ || next;
  my ($id,$word,$star) = ($1,$2,$3);
  print "$id $word $star\n";
}
```

The key thing is the Regular expression:

```
Scheme ID: ([a-z0-9-]+)\s+\(([^)]+)\)\s*(\*)?
```

Which breaks up as follows.

The fixed String "Scheme ID: ":

```
Scheme ID:
```

Followed by one or more of the characters a-z, 0-9 or -.  We use the brackets to capture it as $1:

```
([a-z0-9-]+)
```

Followed by one or more whitespace characters:

```
\s+
```

Followed by an opening bracket (which we escape) followed by any number of characters which aren't a close bracket, and then a closing bracket (escaped).  We use unescaped brackets to capture the words as $2:

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

Followed by some spaces any maybe a *, captured as $3:

```
\s*(\*)?
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression such as the following:

```
/([-a-z0-9]+)\s*\((.*?)\)\s*(\*)?/
```

So for example:

```
$s = "abc-456-hu5t10 (High priority) *";
$s =~ /([-a-z0-9]+)\s*\((.*?)\)\s*(\*)?/;
print "$1\n$2\n$3\n";
```

prints

```
abc-456-hu5t10
High priority
*
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(\S*)\s*\((.*?)\)\s*(\*?)


(\S*)    picks up anything which is NOT whitespace
\s*      0 or more whitespace characters
\(       a literal open parenthesis
(.*?)    anything, non-greedy so stops on first occurrence of...
\)       a literal close parenthesis
\s*      0 or more whitespace characters
(\*?)    0 or 1 occurances of literal *
```

Comment: \(([^)])\) would be better than \((.*?)\), as it's guaranteed to stop at the first ).  Non-greedy quantifiers can cause heavy backtracking, which kills performance.  (Unlikely in this case, admittedly, but avoiding them when they're not needed is still a good habit to cultivate.)  The negated character class is also a clearer statement of your intent - you're looking for "any number of non-) characters", not "the smallest number of any character at all, followed by a ), which makes the expression as a whole match".

Answer (score 2):

Long time no Perl

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    next unless /:\s*(\S+)\s+\(([^\)]+)\)\s*(\*?)/;
    print "|$1|$2|$3|\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, a one liner here:

```
perl -lne 'm|Scheme ID:\s+(.*?)\s+\((.*?)\)\s?(\*)?|g&&print "$1:$2:$3"' file.txt
```

Expanded to a simple script to explain things a bit better:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ln              

#-w : warnings                   
#-l : print newline after every print                               
#-n : apply script body to stdin or files listed at commandline, dont print $_           

use strict; #always do this.     

my $regex = qr{  # precompile regex                                 
  Scheme\ ID:      # to match beginning of line.                      
  \s+              # 1 or more whitespace                             
  (.*?)            # Non greedy match of all characters up to         
  \s+              # 1 or more whitespace                             
  \(               # parenthesis literal                              
    (.*?)            # non-greedy match to the next                     
  \)               # closing literal parenthesis                      
  \s*              # 0 or more whitespace (trailing * is optional)    
  (\*)?            # 0 or 1 literal *s                                
}x;  #x switch allows whitespace in regex to allow documentation.   

#values trapped in $1 $2 $3, so do whatever you need to:            
#Perl lets you use any characters as delimiters, i like pipes because                    
#they reduce the amount of escaping when using file paths           
m|$regex| && print "$1 : $2 : $3";

#alternatively if(m|$regex|) {doOne($1); doTwo($2) ... }
```

Though if it were anything other than formatting, I would implement a main loop to handle files and flesh out the body of the script rather than rely ing on the commandline switches for the looping.

Answer (score 2):

This just requires a small change to my [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440439/how-do-i-get-values-by-perl-string-operations/1440592#1440592):

```
my ($guid, $scheme, $star) = $line =~ m{
    The [ ] Scheme [ ] GUID: [ ]
    ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)          #capture the guid
    [ ]
    \(  (.+)  \)             #capture the scheme 
    (?:
        [ ]
        ([*])                #capture the star 
    )?                       #if it exists
}x;
```

Answer (score 0):

String 1:

```
$input =~ /'^\S+'/;
$s1 = $&;
```

String 2:

```
$input =~ /\(.*\)/;
$s2 = $&;
```

String 3:

```
$input =~ /\*?$/;
$s3 = $&;
```